# tcpdump output is diffferent than pcap file

Tags: pcap, tcpdump

I am trying to understand what should be correct command in which i can get tcpdump command output same as pcap file have.

Current commmand : `tcpdump  -s 0 -A -vvv -i eth0 port 5060`

It's output is same as below :

E..G.M..@.
... .T.<......3`.

While on pcap same packate have below output :

```
I�b��))A�U�&E�{@a� ���O����S
```

How can i get same output as showing in pcap file using tcpdump command ?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: I recommend opening the pcap file in a program like Wireshark for Viewing the packet data. If you're viewing raw pcap on the command line then your terminal is going to be trying to convert the raw bytes to characters. This will show the weird characters shown in your second output.

Comment: @Jboullianne Thanks for reply. Actually i like to see tcpdump command output with weird characters but i dont know which options of tcpdump can help me for that.

Answer (score 1):

As @Jboullianne surmised, you're probably just viewing the raw pcap file by printing it to a terminal window.

Pcap files are *not* text files, and the "terminal emulator" program that provides your terminal window is probably assuming the text it's seeing is UTF-8; not all sequences of raw bytes are valid UTF-8.  The � is probably the Unicode "REPLACEMENT CHARACTER", which the terminal is putting out as a replacement for invalid UTF-8 sequences.

And not everything in a pcap file is packet data, so some of those "weird characters" don't correspond to packet data.

Tcpdump has no option to print the bytes of the packet as UTF-8, so there's no way for the packet dump to show the packet data in that form.